# Javascript change urls in main menu according to language

Tags: javascript, html, url, menu, multilingual

I'm a complete noob on javascript so I would need to know if and how this can be done:

I have a site with 2 languages, English and Italian. The Italian pages are on URL like

> www.mysite.com/ita/index.hmtl

while english pages are on

> www.mysite.com/eng/index.hmtl

The user changes langages from flag icons. 
The problem is, I can't change the menu links separately for ITA and ENG sites, so i can't edit the html directly. So right now when an user goes on the english site, the menu links still point to italian pages.

So is there a javascript code to change ALL urls in the page, so when the user goes to the english version of the site on the page

> www.mysite.com/eng/index.hmtl

all urls will be changed from

> /ita/

to

> /eng/
>    ?

Comment: I'm now using this code:

<script type="text/javascript">
  if(document.URL.indexOf("/aprol/") >= 0){ 
               function replace_url(elem, attr) {
         var elems = document.getElementsByTagName(elem);
         for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
             elems[i][attr] = elems[i][attr].replace('mysite.com/', 'mysite.com/eng/');
     }
}
window.onload = function() {
    replace_url('a', 'href');
    // etc
}
</script>

<a href="http://www.mysite.com/index.html">Link</a>

But the initial "If" doesn't work on chrome or IE, only on firefox.
Can't understand why honestly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to change links

```
var url ='www.mysite.com/eng/index.hmtl', lang = '/ita';

url = url.replace(/\/\w*/,lang);

console.log(url); => www.mysite.com/ita/index.hmtl
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep language in cookie (jquery cookie plugin) and update all references on page load using default or cookie language.

JS

```
$("a.changeLang").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.cookie("lang", $(this).attr("href"));
});


var lang = $.cookie("lang");
$("a").each(function(ref){
    $(ref).attr("href", $(ref).attr("href").replace("ita", lang).replace("eng", lang);
});
```

and HTML

```
<a class="changeLang" href="ita">ITA</a>
<a class="changeLang" href="eng">ENG</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(document.URL.indexOf("/aprol/") >= 0){
           function replace_url(elem, attr) { 
           var elems = document.getElementsByTagName(elem); 
           for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) 
               elems[i][attr] = elems[i][attr].replace('mysite.com/', 'mysite.com/eng/'); 
           } 
    } 
window.onload = function(){ 
    replace_url('a', 'href'); 
}
</script>
```

and this as samlple html link

```
<a href="mysite.com/index.html">Link</a>
```

But it works only on firefox, not on chrome or IE9.

Can't understand why honestly.